# Git Command to find all files using commit message

Tags: git, github, github-api

Is there anyway i can find all the commited files using commit message

eg:
adding A.java B.java

**git commit -m "somemessage to FIX bug "**

adding B.java C.java

**git commit -m "again doing commit to FIX some bug"**

Is there anyway i can find (A ,B, C, D files) using key word "FIX" used in both commit messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git log --grep=FIX --pretty='' --name-status
```

The `--pretty=''` says print none of the usual metadata, the `--name-status`  says list the altered files and a quick characterization of what happened to them, `--grep=FIX` says do this for every commit whose log message contains `FIX`.